# Idiomatic way to pass "out slice" to C function?

Tags: rust, ffi

[Some Windows APIs](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/fn.GetClassNameW.html) take slice as parameter and write to it upon return. It's similar to an out pointer but in slice form (so that caller don't need to pass an extra "length" parameter).

In cases of out pointer, I've been using [MaybeUninit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html), which I think is the idiomatic way in Rust. However, I do not know how to use it in case of slices.

For example, many examples suggest to declare `[MaybeUninit<u16>; 32]`, but how do I pass it to a function that accepts only `&mut [u16]`? I tried `MaybeUninit<[u16; 32]>`, but there is no way to get an uninitialized `&mut T` out of `MaybeUninit`. There is only `as_mut_ptr`, which is pointer, not slice.

Am I supposed to stick to `let x: [u16; 32] = zeroed();` at the moment?

Comment: It is always illegal to construct a reference to unitialized data, so you need to initialize the array before creating a slice reference.

Comment: So in Rust a pointer can be uninitialized, but a reference must always be initialized? So my current code (the `zeroed()`) is the idiomatic way?

Comment: Partly correct. References must be valid at all times, and in particular point to iniitialized memory. The idiomatic way to create an array filled with zeroes is `[0u16; 32]`, though, not the unsafe `zeroed()` function.

Comment: The problem is that the signature of the Rust binding of `GetClassNameW` pretty much _precludes_ calling it on an uninitialized buffer. If this is a valid use case, that should be reported as an issue in the `windows` crate.

Comment: I also feel the function should accept `*mut [u16]` rather than `&mut [u16]`. Since references coerce to raw pointers, changing this should be mostly backwards compatible. (It's not fully backwards compatible since the type of the function pointer will change, but many code simply calling the function should continue working.)

Comment: I'll try to ask `windows` guys to maybe change the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a reference to an uninitialized memory is Undefined Behavior, even if the memory contents are never read. Quoting [the reference, "Behavior considered undefined"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) (emphasis mine):

> - ...
> - Producing an invalid value, even in private fields and locals. "Producing" a value happens any time a value is assigned to or read from a place, **passed to a function**/primitive operation or returned from a function/primitive operation. The following values are invalid (at their respective type):
>
>   - ...
>   - **A reference** or `Box<T>` that is [dangling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#dangling-pointers), unaligned, **or points to an invalid value**.
>
> ...
>
> **Note**: **Uninitialized memory is also implicitly invalid for any type that has a restricted set of valid values**. In other words, the only cases in which reading uninitialized memory is permitted are inside unions and in "padding" (the gaps between the fields/elements of a type).

It is not *obvious* this is UB: there is [an active discussion about that](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/77) (part of the counterarguments is to allow things like your case). However, currently it is considered UB and you should avoid it.

(Note: the "has a restricted set of valid values" is somewhat ambiguous. Whether primitive types like integers are allowed to contain uninitialized bits is [also a matter of active discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/71), but in this case too you should avoid it until it is settled. You may claim the reference does not agree with that, because integers do not have a restricted set of values, but this is false: one can view the set of possible values for a byte as `0`-`256` *and* the `uninit` byte, and in fact this is an interpretation used in many places. Integers cannot contain the `uninit` byte and so have a restricted set of values).

Initializing the array using `mem::zeroed()` is sound but uses `unsafe` for no reason: you can just use an initialized, i.e. `[0; size]`, and it will be just as performant.

Comment: I like `zeroed` because I find `[0; size]` unnecessarily repeats the size. It's not like I can initialize the array with a different size anyways. Plus I'm already doing unsafe stuff.

Comment: @CrendKing (a) Minimizing unsafe is an important goal, much more than some redundancy (in fact, when writing unsafe code I use a lot of redundancy _on purpose_ to minimize the chance for mistakes). (b) You don't have to repeat the size, specify it only in the initializer. (c) [You will be able to infer the size in the future](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/85077) (or using nightly).

Comment: @CrendKing Also, a good `unsafe` block should have a preceding `// SAFETY:` comment, and with it the `zeroed()` version is longer ;)

Comment: I think this problem suggests a more general long-standing design problem, or oversight at least, with the Rust language, because the pattern of passing a static uninitialized array to a function and receiving the resulting slice is a fundamental pattern for implementing fast, efficient code operating on statically allocated storage. This is one of multiple issues that are usually shrugged off by rust designers and users, but are actually "false positives" triggered by the rust safety system that result in small inefficiencies piling up on the resulting programs. Rust is 12 years old already.

Answer (score 0):

You do not canonically need `MaybeUninit`, you can fill a buffer array with zeroes yourself:

```rust
let x: [u16; 32] = [0u16; 32];

let res = unsafe { GetClassNameW(param0, &mut x); }
```

Comment: I was using `zeroed()` because obviously I'm already doing unsafe stuff, and `zeroed()` seems less verbose than `[0u16; 32]`. Other than unsafety, is there any subtle difference?

Comment: Well, I suggest that not using unsafe is difference enough